# swapping characters without using third variable

Tags: c

characters in C are actually some ascii numbers. Then why following code, which is supposed to swap two characters, gives wrong result

```
void swap(char *a,char *b)
{
    *a=*a+*b;
    *b=*a-*b;
    *a=*a-*b;
}
```

Comment: What is your input? What result are you getting?

Comment: i am sending addresses of two characters, say swap(&ch1,&ch2)

Comment: You can also use the preprocessor: `#define SWAP(a, b)  do { a ^= b; b ^= a; a ^= b; } while ( 0 )`

Comment: @codemonkey that will fail horribly if a and b are equal.

Comment: That will easily overflow `*a` if for example `*a == 150, *b = 151`. You should not use this kind of tricks, there is no real benefit from them.

Comment: Using a temp var is prolly quicker anyway, apart from the 'gruesome obfuscation' issue, the 'pontless pseudo-optimization' issue and the 'doesn't work' issue.

Comment: I don't know why I got negative rating for asking this? Is that a duplicate question?

Comment: @user3437973 Probably because you didn't provide input values and output values. You should add those to the original question.

Comment: How about a short program that shows it failing?  I suspect the `ch1` and `ch2` in your `swap(&ch1,&ch2)` aren't actually `char` -- maybe `char *`?  or `int`?  Also, what platform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The calculation, in theory, looks fine. Let's work through it by example:

Let's take `a = 'S' = 83` and `b = 'O' = 79`.

```
a = a + b = 83 + 79 = 162
```

If your compiler defines `char` to be unsigned, we have no problem with overflows. If your compiler defines `char` to be signed, this is out of range (> 127) and results in `a = -94`.

```
b = a - b = (-94) - 79 = -173
```

is out of range again and yields 83, which is ok.

```
a = a - b = (-94) - (-173) - = 79
```

This also looks good.

Actually, this code works for me with no problem:

```
char a = 'S', b = 'O';
swap(&a, &b);
assert(a == 'O');
assert(b == 'S');
```

Using the exact `swap` function you provided.

Here is [full working example code](https://ideone.com/K3Z1Tc).

Comment: The last time he sets `*a` it's actually `a = a - b = (a + b) - a = b`, not `a = a - b = a - a = 0`... since he's already set `*a=*a+*b;` at that point.  His problem is something else.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
 
int main()
{
   int a, b;
 
   printf("Enter two integers to swap\n");
   scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
 
   a = a + b;
   b = a - b;
   a = a - b;
 
   printf("a = %d\nb = %d\n",a,b);
   return 0;
}
This works fine

Comment: @Daerst the reason you gave is actually the reason for "why i can't  swap the value at same address" i.e. if a=b, then why can't i swap a number with itself.

Comment: I changed the answer and removed my original faulty mathematical explanation. The code works fine for me. @user3437973, please provide us real input that fails.

Comment: @Daerst Even for a='a' and b='b', it failed!

Comment: @user3437973 Not for me, the values are swapped correctly using Visual Studio 2012. The error must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 5):

The result would be weird if the above expression will result in arithmetic overflow. The above method will also fail in case both pointers `a` and `b` points to the same location<sup>*</sup>.

Try this:

```
void swap(char *a,char *b)
{
    if (a == b) // Check if the two addresses are same
      return;

    *a=*a^*b;
    *b=*a^*b;
    *a=*a^*b;
}
```

---

*If `a` and `b` will point to same location say `x100` and let the value stored at that location is `0111`(in binary), then:

```
*a = *a ^ *b   // *a will have now 0000 
*b = *a ^ *b   // *b = 0000^0000 = 0000  
*a = *a ^ *b   // *a = 0000^0000 = 0000
```

Comment: Comparing the addresses is not enough. Equal values in different locations will still lead to 0.

Comment: @Daerst: I'm considering betting my to-date career earnings on your being incorrect here ;-)

Comment: even i tried XOR for swapping characters. It didn't work

Comment: @user3437973; what is your input?

Comment: i am sending addresses of two characters, say swap(&ch1,&ch2)

Comment: What is the value of `ch1` and `ch2`? What result are you getting?

Comment: @haccks ch1='a' ch2='b'

Answer (score 1):

Two issues

1. Your last line `*a=*a-*b;` actually boils down to `*a=*a-*a;`
2. `char` could be either `signed` or `unsigned`. That's a choice that your compiler makes; the C standard allows either. So the value of `*a-*b` could differ from platform to platform.

It *is* possible to swap without a temporary. The technique (XOR swapping) is well-documented, but its use not recommended due to some nasty edge-cases.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work, if the pointers are equal. So this needs to be checked and handled first.

To figure out the issue on your machine, you should write a test like the following and analyse the results with additional printf outputs for example:

```
void swap(char *a, char *b)
{
    /* if (a != b){ */
    *a = *a + *b;
    *b = *a - *b;
    *a = *a - *b;
    /*}*/
}

void swapTemp(char *a, char *b)
{
    char temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int
main(){
    unsigned int errors = 0;
    int b;
    for (b = 0; b <= 255; b++)
    {
        int a;
        for (a = 0; a <= 255; a++)
        {
            char a_swap = a;
            char a_swapTemp = a;
            char b_swap = b;
            char b_swapTemp = b;
            swap(&a_swap, &b_swap);
            swapTemp(&a_swapTemp, &b_swapTemp);
            if ((a_swap != a_swapTemp) || (b_swap != b_swapTemp))
                ++errors;
            /* extend to print results here to analyse the problem */
        }
    }
    printf("There where %u errors!", errors);
    return 0;
}
```

Give more information about your machine, compiler and test results!

Answer (score -2):

if you just write them without '*' and without '&' like a normal integer swapping program it will work.